# Visual Studio 2013 Community - Generating PDB Files - No Advanced Debug Options

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, pdb-files

Probably something stupid, but I can't seem to find any PDB files anywhere for C# web api project. I am trying to debug remotely but the symbol files don't load and I've tried everything else in my power to fix that. 
Most places say set your debug info to full/pdb-only but I don't have the option. Everywhere I look online it tells me to go to My Project, right click Properties(I only have Property Pages option), Build, Advanced Build settings, and all I see is this:

[image]

Is it my project type or something? I swear the older versions of visual studio had nice property/configuration pages with everything you could ever want in them. It seems like everything online tells me to go to places and menus that I can never find.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Go to Tools->Options->Debugging and then Symbols and in there you should see your own location of the pdb-files.

Comment: Yea but there is only the Microsoft Symbol Servers location. I don't think they were ever being made.